# Creating Method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have several of these instances I have to call to pull down data from a crm server.

```
RetrieveAttributeRequest request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
request.EntityLogicalName = "opportunity";
request.LogicalName = "new_businessunit";
RetrieveAttributeResponse response = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)lService.Execute(request);
PicklistAttributeMetadata picklist = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata;

RetrieveAttributeRequest requestsource = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
requestsource.EntityLogicalName = "opportunity";
requestsource.LogicalName = "new_sourcepick";
RetrieveAttributeResponse responsesource = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)lService.Execute(requestsource);
PicklistAttributeMetadata picklistsource = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)responsesource.AttributeMetadata;

Dictionary<int?, string> BusinessUnits = new Dictionary<int?, string>();
foreach (OptionMetadata option in picklist.OptionSet.Options)
    {
        string picklistlabel = option.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label.ToString();
        businessid = option.Value;
        BusinessUnits.Add(businessid, picklistlabel);
    }
Dictionary<int?, string> MarketSegment = new Dictionary<int?, string>();
foreach (OptionMetadata option in picklistmarket.OptionSet.Options)
    {
        string picklistlabel = option.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label.ToString();
        marketid = option.Value;
        MarketSegment.Add(marketid, picklistlabel);
    }
```

So basically I pull the data down and then build a dictionary to hold the data. I have a lot of these so I would like to make a method where I just pass the EntityLogialName and the LogicalName. So instead of having all that I could do something like:

loadlist(opportuniuty, new_businessunit)

But I'm not really sure how to make the method to handle it. Any ideas on how I would do the method?

Thanks!

Comment: how many different dictionary declarations do you have. I see you add to BusinessUnits and MarketSegment how many others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IDictionary<int?, string> LoadFromCRM(string entityName, string logicalName)
{
    var request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
    request.EntityLogicalName = entityName;
    request.LogicalName = logicalName;
    var response = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)lService.Execute(request);
    var picklist = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata;

    return picklist.OptionSet.Options.ToDictionary(o => o.Value, o => o.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label.ToString());
}

// Usage
var businessUnits = LoadFromCRM("opportunity", "new_businessunit");
var marketSegment = LoadFromCRM("opportunity", "new_sourcepick");
```

Encapsulate the loading of any data within a method, and call it twice (once for each set of data you're interested in). The above uses LINQ to translate the `Options` into a `Dictionary` using the `ToDictionary` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method:

```
public static class PicklistAttributeMetadataExtensions
{
public static Dictionary<int?,string> ToDictionary(this PicklistAttributeMetadata picklist)
{
  return picklist.OptionSet.Options.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => option.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label.ToString());
}    
}
```

Used like this:

```
PicklistAttributeMetadata picklist = /// get pick list
var dictionary = picklist.ToDictionary();
```